# Decode GPS Data

Tags: parsing, gps, format

I have a GPS tracker . It's a chinese model, with sparse documentation. It's got a built in gps and a gprs module (sim) and it's sending me my data to a particular ip address.
No idea what the format is
I using "template" OpenGTS server
Log:

```
[INFO_|06/20 11:47:28|TrackClientPacketHandler.sessionStarted:256] Begin TCP communication: 84.15.15.12 [Mon Jun 20 11:47:28 EE ST 2011]
[INFO_|06/20 11:47:37|TrackClientPacketHandler.parseInsertRecord_ASCII_1:565] Parsing: �32472798�?
[WARN_|06/20 11:47:37|TrackClientPacketHandler.parseInsertRecord_ASCII_1:576] Invalid number of fields
[WARN_|06/20 11:47:41|ServerSocketThread$ServerSessionThread.readPacket:2001] Timeout: 0x007F070F00FFFFFFFF00F0640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B822511D1013031E00067360215281F2000000000630079659105100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B4
[WARN_|06/20 11:47:41|ServerSocketThread$ServerSessionThread.run:1527] Read timeout [@ 115]
[INFO_|06/20 11:47:41|ServerSocketThread$ServerSessionThread.run:1550] End of session ...
[INFO_|06/20 11:47:41|TrackClientPacketHandler.sessionTerminated:270] End TCP communication: 84.15.15.12
```

�32472798�? is part of IMEI number
Please help to understand data format

Comment: What is the model?  Does it use NMEA format?  Can youi show some of the raw data from the device?

Comment: As JeremyP said, we need the raw format to help you. Raw format are like sentence starting like that "$GPRMC".

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve this. [See my question]((http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851424/handling-node-js-socket-data) . Your support is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this tracker uses a binary protocol and it will be too hard to implement this protocol without documentation.