# Handling Node.js socket data

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, sockets, networking

I have server receiving data from a client [GPS Device]. I have problem presenting the data (i.e the results obtained from the client) in a readable format. Below are the things I have tried.

Doing:

```
console.log(data)
```

I get

```
<Buffer d0 d7 3d 00 c4 56 7e 81>
```

Also tried

```
 console.log(data.toString())
```

But I get unwanted results:See below:

```
��A�V~�
```

Here is my full code:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  console.log('Server started: Waiting for client connection ...');
  console.log('Client connected:port,address: '+socket.remotePort,      socket.remoteAddress);
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
        var date = new Date();
        var today = date.getDate()+'_'+date.getMonth();
        fs.appendFile(today+'_log.txt', data, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data.toString())

    });
 });
});

server.listen(my_port, my_ip);
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Any idea about the data getting received? Whether it is base64 encoded or ascii?

Comment: No clear details on encoding used. One of my biggest problem. The protocal doc doesn't show

Comment: Not much help without knowing that. Trial and error might work. Here's a doc that can help. http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers

Comment: I have found somewhere in the vendor website talking about 'ISO-8859-1' encoding standard. Let me find out about it.

Comment: ascii encoding gave me this result - `PW=\u0000DV~\u0001` This is the only one that made some sense to me.

Comment: Confirmed: It is a 7-bit ascii encoding. Let me try it in code.

Comment: Finally found the protocol document.Seems alot to be done > http://www.scribd.com/doc/145817155/GPRS-Vehicle-Tracker-Protocol-NR006-NR024

Answer (score 10):

According to the documentation, you must specify an encoding to get a String instead of a Buffer:

```
Event: 'data'#
Buffer object
Emitted when data is received. The argument data will be a Buffer or String. Encoding of data is set by socket.setEncoding().
```

You could configure the socket to get the data in UTF-8, for example, with:

```
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {
        var buff = Buffer.from(data);
```

But remember, lots of GPS devices use little-endian, so later you're going to have to decode the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data in buffer is 7 bit ASCII,

```
console.log(data.toString('ascii'))
```

would resolve the problem.